# SQL-Server for Linux WORKGROUP authentication handling

Tags: sql-server, linux, windows, authentication

I installed SQL-Server for Linux on a linux Centos 7 distro, it works fine, but I need a workgroup authentication. It's required by the client (SAGE Ligne 100) which runs on a Windows workstation. There is no domain controller, just these two machins.
Can SQL-Server for Linux handle workgroup authentication, and how ? Thanks.
NB : I already posted that question to https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/397194/sql-server-for-linux-workgroup-authentication-handling